# Where does custom IRouteConstraint get discovered by ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, routes

I'm digging the source code to see how asp.net core discovery custom `IRouteConstraint`.

We know that when we define a custom `IRouteConstraint`, we add it to `RouteOptions` as

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) 
{
    services.Configure<RouteOptions>(opts => {
        opts.ConstraintMap.Add("countryName", typeof(CountryRouteConstraint));
    });  
}

public class CountryRouteConstraint: IRouteConstraint 
{
    public bool Match(...) { ... }
}
```

where `IOptions<RouteOptions>` is registered.

So I check the source code of

- `EndpointRoutingMiddleware` (https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing/EndpointRoutingMiddleware.cs,e91e5febd7b6da29)
- `DfaMatcher`
  (https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing/Matching/DfaMatcher.cs,0b08e610bec2cfbc)

and so on, I didn't find any part of the source code that tries to read from `RouteOptions` to discovery custom `IRouteConstraint`.

This is the place I think most likely https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing/Matching/DfaMatcher.cs,197
but still doesn't find anything.

Can anybody show me the section of the source code that ASP.NET Core read from `RouteOptions` to discovery custom `IRouteConstraint`?

Comment: Why do you need to know where exactly the `RouteOptions` are registered?

Answer (score 1):

Navigate to that [`ConstraintMap`](https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing/RouteOptions.cs,71) property of `RouteOptions`, to which you are adding your `CountryRouteConstraint` constraint.

Look for its [references](https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing/RouteOptions.cs,0251b77d939f6c00,references).

The ones of most interest for you are

- [`DefaultInlineConstraintResolver`](https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing/DefaultInlineConstraintResolver.cs,37)
- [`DefaultParameterPolicyFactory`](https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing/DefaultParameterPolicyFactory.cs,46)

Both make use of the [`ParameterPolicyActivator`](https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing/ParameterPolicyActivator.cs) for the instantation of the constraints, passing in that `ConstraintMap`.

E.g. [DefaultParameterPolicyFactory](https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing/DefaultParameterPolicyFactory.cs,46) shows below

```
 var parameterPolicy = ParameterPolicyActivator.ResolveParameterPolicy<IParameterPolicy>(
    _options.ConstraintMap,
    _serviceProvider,
    inlineText,
    out var parameterPolicyKey);
```